# Billing flow not launching on button click

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I followed a tutorial online and I'm struggling to launch the billing flow on button click. When the button is clicked absolutely nothing happens. Everything in terms of subscription details is correct. I did upload it for testing and found that it still doesn't work.

```
 subscribeAbstract = view.findViewById(R.id.abstract_subscribe_btn)

        subscribeAbstract.setOnClickListener {

            billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    val productList = listOf(
                        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                            .setProductId("abstract_wallpapers")
                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                            .build())

                    val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setProductList(productList)
                    billingClient!!.queryProductDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->

                        for (productDetails in productDetailsList) {
                            val offerToken =
                                productDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.offerToken
                            val productDetailsParamsList =
                                listOf(
                                    offerToken?.let {
                                        BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                                            .setOfferToken(it)
                                            .build()
                                    }
                                )
                            val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                                .build()

                            val billingResult = billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), billingFlowParams)
                        }
                    }
                }
```